# How to set footer position absolute or relative depending on content size?

Tags: css, css-position

I want to do something like this:
[image]

In case 1: content height is smaller than window.
In case 2: content height is larger than window - and scroll shows,

My problem is that content is dynamically changed. So, sometimes .cont height is larger than window height. And then, .foot should be beneath of .cont.

If I set this code

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.cont{
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#333;
    width:800px;
    height:500px;
}
.foot {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin:0 0 0 -400px;
    background-color:#F33;
    width:800px;
    height:20px;
    bottom:0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="cont"></div>
    <div class="foot"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I get this:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can modify the markup slightly, try [Ryan Fait's Sticky Footer](https://web.archive.org/web/20120929143537/http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/) approach:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -4em;
}
 .footer, .push {
    height: 4em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <p>Your website content here.</p>
    <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <p>Copyright (c) 2008</p>
</div>
```

On his website, he mentions the code solution is free to use without license.